# Как отловить ошибку правильно?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь делать отлов ошибок следующим образом:

```
window.onerror = (msg, file, line, col, error) => {}
```

Но, какая ошибка бы не была - `error = null`, `msg = Script error`.

Скрипту указал атрибут `crossorigin="anonymous"`, сервер отвечает заголовком `access-control-allow-origin:*`.

Почему это происходит и что я не учел ?

**UPDATE**

Скрипт подключаю так - `<script src='static-js.com/.../file.js' crossorigin="anonymous" />`. У самого сайта другой домен. В этом же скрипте эмулирую ошибку вида:

```
const b = null; b.get();
```

И пытаюсь отловить ее скриптом выше, выводя `msg & error` в консоль. (Обработчик ошибки находится в этом же файле).

В консоли в `Network` при загрузке скрипта в `Response Headers` содержится заголок, указанный выше.

Comment: `onerror` же только ошибки загрузки ловит? или это и нужно?

Comment: да. В принципе нужны все ошибки, которые могут произойти в процессе отработки js.

Comment: где указал атрибут? на что отвечает сервер? как проверяешь значение error и msg?

Comment: @Grundy дополнил вопрос